# How to close correctly a WINAPI Thread pool cancelling pending tasks

Tags: multithreading, winapi, threadpool

I have a question about closing a WINAPI ThreadPool.

Suppose i have initialized a thread pool with a cleanup group and pushed some tasks to the thread pool with the SubmitThreadpoolWork.
I'm calling the CloseThreadPoolTask in the task's callback function.

Currently there are tasks that executing and others that pending in the thread-pool's queue.

Now, for closing the thread pool I want to use CloseThreadpoolCleanupGroupMembers function without pending for the queued tasks to finish, **but I still want to get a callback to the pending task to release its user allocated resources (some that come with the task's parameters).**

I saw in this thread:
[Cancelling scheduled work/io/timer items in WIN32 thread pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220410/cancelling-scheduled-work-io-timer-items-in-win32-thread-pool)

that the callback that i have passed to the cleanup group (PTP_CLEANUP_GROUP_CANCEL_CALLBACK)  will also call to work objects that are currently executing (because they still tied to cleanup group during the execution) - obviously i don't want it to happen... Is there a way that the cleanup cancel callback will not get invoked on currently executing tasks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if callback for CreateThreadpoolWork begin executed, cleanup callback for it will be not called. or if cancel callback for item will be called - `PTP_WORK_CALLBACK` will be never called for this item (before and after). so here really no any problem. or will be called your `PTP_WORK_CALLBACK` or will be called cancell callback for this item. this is mutually exclusive. so reply in topic [Cancelling scheduled work/io/timer items in WIN32 thread pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220410/cancelling-scheduled-work-io-timer-items-in-win32-thread-pool) containing very serious errors. i can suggest you for test insert `MessageBox` call in begin of `PTP_WORK_CALLBACK` and also another `MessageBox` before `CloseThreadpoolCleanupGroupMembers`. and you can make sure if `PTP_WORK_CALLBACK` begin executed - cancell callback for this item already not called.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!

I have tested this thing according to what you said and i have another points to make clear.

I have used a pool with 1 thread and pushed 5 tasks that sleeps for 1 minute.

After calling CloseThreadpoolCleanupGroupMembers the cleanup cancell callback was called only after the thread have finished

and its work and it was called only 4 times (only for the pending jobs)